# Radio Button Inside Javascript

Tags: php, radio-button

i have this radio button result from dropdown menu that i have called using ajax. But i have no result return from the radio button that i clicked. What is the problem with this script?

```
<script>
....................
var sScript="<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>";
sScript = sScript + "<script defer>";
sScript = sScript + "$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){ var radioValue = $("input[name='choose']:checked").val(); if(radioValue){ $('#radioresult').val($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()); console.log(radioValue) } });";
sScript = sScript + "</script>";

var htmlss= '<div class="ajxstyle"><table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Radio</th><th>Shipping Name</th><th>Shipping Fee</th><th>Shipping Time</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    htmlss += '<tr>';
    htmlss += '<td><input type="radio" name="choose"  value="'+value.shipping_fee+'" onclick"funsio();"></td>';
    htmlss += '<td>'+value.shipping_name+'</td>';
    htmlss += '<td>'+value.shipping_fee+'</td>';
    htmlss += '<td>'+value.shipping_time+'</td>';
    htmlss += '</tr>';
    htmlss += '</tbody></table>';
    txtHint.innerHTML = htmlss + sScript;
</script>
<body>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: In the code you gave above, `value` wasn't defined. Can you share whats the error you have on console?

Comment: i've got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: ok i've fixed it by replacing the var sScript to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by changing the var sScript to

```
           var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.type = 'text/javascript';
            var code = 'function check(browser){';
                code += 'document.getElementById("answer").value=browser;}';
            try {
                s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
                document.body.appendChild(s);
            } catch (e) {
                s.text = code;
                document.body.appendChild(s);
            }
```